# c++ Linked List losing data between functions

Tags: c++, pointers, scope

I am having a problem with pointers and scope. I am trying to maintain an array of linked lists of pointers to objects. When I try to push_front() in one function, it works. However, if I try to iterate through the list in another part of my program, the list no longer contains any data, and my pointers are bad.

This is part of my parseCommands function. the problem is when printList is called:

```
                    Administrator *adminPtr = new Administrator(); // create new Administrator pointer

                    //local variables...
                    string adminName;   //administrator's name
                    int adminMNum;  //administrator's M Number
                    string adminEmail;  //administrator's email address
                    string adminTitle;  // administrator's title

                    // read in & store data for new administrator
                    inData >> adminName; //read in data
                    adminPtr->setName(adminName); //set admin name

                    inData >> adminMNum;
                    adminPtr->setMNum(adminMNum);   // set admin M Number

                    inData >> adminEmail;
                    adminPtr->setEmail(adminEmail); // set admin email address

                    inData >> adminTitle;
                    adminPtr->setTitle(adminTitle); //set admin title
                    // finished storing new administrator info

                    // add Administrator to list
                    cout << "Adding Administrator: " << endl;
                    cout << "in records office adminPtr/newPerson: " << adminPtr << endl;
                    universityList.addPerson(adminPtr);  // call addPerson--hashTable
                    //universityList.printPerson(adminPtr);     // print admin info using polymorphic method
                    //cout << "The load factor (alpha) is: " << universityList.getLength()/universityList.getMaxTableSize() << endl;    // print alpha
                    universityList.printList(adminPtr->getMNum());  // print all items at table[loc]--breaks here
                    cout << endl;
```

The addPerson function where printList works fine:

```
template <typename T>
void HashTable<T>::addPerson(T newPerson) { //newPerson is a pointer to a person object
  int loc;  // array location provided by hashFunction
  cout << "in hashtable newPerson: " << newPerson << endl;
  loc = hashFunction(newPerson->getMNum());  // get loc
  table[loc].push_front(&newPerson);  // add to list at table[loc] passing address of pointer to person
  printList(newPerson->getMNum());  // print all items at table[loc]--works here
  size++;   // increment size
  } //end function
```

The printList function that works when called in addPerson, but not in parseCommands:

```
template <typename T>
void HashTable<T>::printList(searchKeyType key) {   //print list of items held in array location
    int loc = hashFunction(key);    // get array location
    if (table[loc].empty()) {   // if list is empty
        cout << "Can not print person M" << key << " NOT found" << endl << endl; 
    }   //end if empty
  else{
    list<T*>::iterator iter;    // stl iterator
    iter = table[loc].begin();
    cout << "in printList table[loc]begin " << *iter << endl;   //print address of table[loc]begin.()--where iter points
    cout << "in printList item in table[loc]begin " << **iter << endl;  // print address of the pointer that iter points to
    while(iter != table[loc].end()) { // for each item in the list

        (**iter)->print();  // print person info using polymorphic method
        ++iter;
    }   //end for
  } // end else
}   // end printList
```

The print function:

```
void Administrator::print()const {  
// print Administrator info
cout << "   " << "Full Name:    " << getName() << endl;
cout << "   " << "M Number :    "<< getMNum() << endl;
cout << "   " << "Email Addr:   " << getEmail() << endl;
cout << "   " << "Title:        "   << getTitle() << endl;
}; // end print function
```

The hashTable class:

```
template<typename T>
class HashTable{
public:
    HashTable(); // constructor
    bool isEmpty()const; //determines if the hash table is empty
    int getLength() const;  // returns (size) number of Persons in table (accessor)
    int getMaxTableSize() const;    // returns tableSize (size of array)
    void addPerson(T person);   // adds new Person 
    void removePerson(searchKeyType key);   // deletes Person from the HashTable
    void printPerson(T person); // prints Person info
    T getNodeItem(int mNumber); //returns person object (accessor)
    void printList(searchKeyType key);  //print list of items held in array location

private:
    int size;   // number of Persons in table
    static const int tableSize = 1; // number of buckets/array size -- planning on using 70001--assuming 35,000 entries at once; largest prime > 2*35000
    list <T*> table[tableSize]; // array of STL lists for chains
    int hashFunction(searchKeyType searchKey);  // hash function to return location (array index) of item
}; //end HashTable class
```

I pass adminPtr to addPerson, and it seems to add it to the list. Why am I losing the data when I return to the parseCommands function? Is it a stack vs. heap issue? Do I need "new" somewhere? There are a few extra lines in there where I was printing out the address of the pointers trying to figure out what's going on.

This was a programming problem for a class that I was unable to resolve. We had to simulate a hash table using an array of STL linked lists. We were not allowed to use vectors, maps, etc. The program involves an abstract base class (Person) with derived classes (Administrator, etc.) and a templated hash table class. There is one more class (RecordsOffice) that holds the hash table.

```
class RecordsOffice {
public:
    RecordsOffice();    // default constructor
    void parseCommands(string fileName);    // function to parse commands from a file to maintain the StudentList

private:
    HashTable <Person*> universityList; // creates empty hashtable
};
```

Comment: You may do well to consider defining a Node type for your hash table template that holds a by-val copy of the items being pushed in (which may be a pointer and if so, a *smart pointer* to allow polymorphic access), with the collision list pointer data managed as part of the *node*, **not** part of the user-type requirements of the item being added. That aside, answers below address the immediate problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in these two places.

```
universityList.addPerson(adminPtr); 

//...
```

You are passing a copy of adminPtr.

```
template <typename T>
void HashTable<T>::addPerson(T newPerson) { //newPerson is a pointer to a person object
// ...
  table[loc].push_front(&newPerson);  // add to list at table[loc] passing address of pointer to person
// ....
  }
```

`newPerson` is a local variable to `addPerson`. When it returns it is no more valid. But you are adding it´s address in to the table.

the issue is that

```
list <T*> table[tableSize];
```

is storing pointers to pointers of Person.

I don't think passing by reference would solve the problem too. Because then you will be dependent on the automatically created pointer here.

```
Administrator *adminPtr = new Administrator();
```

**What `adminPtr` pointer points to will stay but not `adminPtr`  itself**. So you can not depend on its address (*unless you are sstill in the same function that created it*). One possible way to solve it would be to allocate adminPtr   itself dynamically.

```
Administrator **adminPtr = new Administrator*;
adminPtr = new Administrator();
```

But maybe you should revise the requirements.

Comment: @user2048220 Passing by value is not specific to pointers only. Anything can be passed by value. What it means is what ever is in what is in passed will be copied. The problem is when taking the address of an **automatically created variable** (pointer or not). **The address is not valid anymore once you return from the function that created it**.

Answer (score 1):

Your table is declared like this:

```
list <T*> table[tableSize];
```

That means any pointers it contains need to be dynamically allocated, or need to remain in scope for the entire lifetime of the container.  This is not the case.  In your function `addPerson` you add the address of a local variable:

```
table[loc].push_front(&newPerson);
```

You should do one of the following:

1. Change the table to an array of `list<T>` objects.
2. Copy the data dynamically. *eg* `table[loc].push_front(new T(newPerson))`

Because this is a list, I would go for option 1 because the list will copy locally anyway, and you won't have to clean up the pointers later.  A third option would be to use `list<unique_ptr<T> >` or similar.